# error while loading shared libraries: libmpifort.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: compiler-errors, openmpi, ubuntu-22.04

I am a beginner to Linux OS and compiling codes in general. I am trying to compile a numerical code that requires openmpi.

I am using windows subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu jammy). when I run the propragm the following error message appear

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmpifort.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

from online search, I guess that I should install the missing lib file. However, I get this message

```
sudo apt install libmpifort.so.12
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmpifort.so.12
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libmpifort.so.12'
```

could you please help me?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get install mpich' did not solve the problem